# Excel cell formula scope rules for selecting VBA modules

Tags: worksheet-function, vba

Suppose I have a macro-enabled Excel workbook `Q.xlsm` containing two user-defined modules `A` and `B`, and each module has a public function named `xyz()` where `A::xyz()` returns a `STRING` object, and `B::xyz()` returns an `INTEGER` value.

```
Q.xlsm
`-- Modules
    |-- A
    |   `-- Public Function xyz() As String
    `-- B
        `-- Public Function xyz() As Integer
```

*Q1) What is the worksheet cell formula scoping syntax that allows me to invoke either `A::xyz()` or `B::xyz()`?*

Another case would be two macro-enabled workbooks `P.xlsm` and `Q.xlsm`, each with a user-defined module `A` having a public function `xyz()`. Suppose workbook `P` is saved as an add-in module `P.xlam`, and that this add-in is in fact "added in" to Excel (e.g., File > Options... > Add-Ins > ...). Now when I open workbook `Q.xlsm` I have two public functions `P.xlam::A::xyz()` and `Q::A::xyz()`,

```
P.xlam (add-in)
|-- Modules
|   `-- A
|       `-- Public Function xyz() As String
Q.xlsm
`-- Modules
    `-- A
        `-- Public Function xyz() As Integer
```

*Q2) If I enter `=xyz()` into a worksheet cell, how do I know which function is invoked (i.e., what are the scope rules for VBA function names within worksheet cells)?*

*Q3) What syntax do I use in the worksheet cell formula to invoke either `P.xlam::A::xyz()` or `Q.xlsm::A::xyz()`?*

Comment: As far as I know there are no official way of overloading functions in VBA. In your first scenario you'll likely get an error message, while in second case either the macro from the same workbook will be called, or you get an error message. Anyway it's a very bad practice to use functions with the same name.

Comment: Why to use the same xyz() use different Function

Comment: The point of the question is to learn the scoping rules and language syntax, not to debate whether or not having multiple functions named 'xyz()' is sensible or not. There are cases--e.g., when using 3rd party add-ins--where name collisions do occur, and re-naming published functions is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Q1) What is the worksheet cell formula scoping syntax that allows me to invoke either `A::xyz()` or `B::xyz()`?*

A1) The worksheet cell formula scoping syntax seems to be `MODULE_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME()`, e.g.,

```
=A.xyz()   // Returns the String object
=B.xyz()   // Returns the Integer value
```

> *Q2) If I enter `=xyz()` into a worksheet cell [in workbook `Q.xlsm`] , how do I know which function is invoked (i.e., what are the scope rules for VBA function names within worksheet cells)?*

A2) After some testing with Excel 2016, invoking `=xyz()` within a worksheet cell in workbook `Q.xlsm` invokes the add-in version `P.xlam!A.xyz()` and not `Q.xlsm!A.xyz()`.

> *Q3) What syntax do I use in the worksheet cell formula [in workbook `Q.xlsm`] to invoke either `P.xlam::A::xyz()` or `Q.xlsm::A::xyz()`?*

A3) The scoping syntax seems to be `WORKBOOK_FILE_NAME!MODULE_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME()`,

```
=P.xlam!A.xyz()     // returns STRING, becomes `=A.xyz()`
=Q.xlsm!A.xyz()     // returns INTEGER
```

If function `xyz()` is not overloaded within any other modules within the workbook `Q.xlsm`, then the shorthand scoping syntax `WORKBOOK_FILE_NAME!FUNCTION_NAME()` also works, e.g.,

```
=P.xlam!xyz()       // returns STRING, becomes `=xyz()`
=Q.xlsm!xyz()       // returns INTEGER
```

**EDIT 2017-11-27**

Another useful scope syntax that can be used in cell formulas:

```
'[workbook_file_path]worksheet_name'!range_within_worksheet_name
```

Examples:

```
'[C:\Temp\Workbook1.xlsx]Scores'!$B$10
'[Workbook2.xlsx]Roster'!Teams
```

If anyone knows of a built-in, shortcut syntax that describes "this workbook's full path" and is suitable for use as the "[workbook_file_path]" field, please comment. *(n.b., I'm not talking about creating an `INDIRECT()` kludge that uses `=CELL("filename",A1)` or some variant thereof.)*